# How do I use a more generic selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

The following code is coming from a SharePoint form where I've injected some jQuery to hide and show a section based on radio button selection of Yes or No. I don't have any control over the HTML output really since it's coming from a SP form. The jQuery selector below works as it is now but I'd like to make it more generic so it's not tied to any input ID. If I copy this form from a dev SP server to another the IDs change.

Current jQuery selector that is working against the HTML output below:

```
// Password expire = Yes
if ($("input[id='ctl00_m_g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581_ff111_ctl00_ctl00']").is(':checked')) {
  $("#PasswordExpireReason").hide();
}

// Password expire = No
if ($("input[id='ctl00_m_g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581_ff111_ctl00_ctl01']").is(':checked')) {
  $("#PasswordExpireReason").show();
}
```

---

HTML output:

```
<span title="Yes" class="ms-RadioText">
  <input name="ctl00$m$g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581$ff111$ctl00$RadioButtons" id="ctl00_m_g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581_ff111_ctl00_ctl00" type="radio" value="ctl00">
  <span title="No" class="ms-RadioText">
  <input name="ctl00$m$g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581$ff111$ctl00$RadioButtons" id="ctl00_m_g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581_ff111_ctl00_ctl01" type="radio" value="ctl01">
  </span>
</span>
```

Since both radio buttons have a span title of "Yes" and "No" around them is there a way I can get the match the closest input given a span title of Yes or No?  The point is, matching each radio using the span instead of the input's id.

Thanks!

Comment: I mean, yeah, you can use an attribute equals selector, just like your current selectors.

Comment: Can you update the HTML so your `<span>`s are more properly nested? The first `<span>` should be closed after the first `<input>`. Then you could use `span[title="yes"] > input` and `span[title="no"] > input`. Otherwise, `input[value="ctl00"]` and `input[value="ctl01"]` should suffice.

Comment: As is, try `$('span.ms-RadioText[title=Yes] > input:first-child')` for the yes, and `$('span.ms-RadioText[title=No] + input')` for the no.

Comment: your html looks wrong, <span> tag is not properly nested.

Comment: Select any input with `$("input")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way to do this would be to write a generic selector for the radio button. If this is the only radio input on this page then, you can write something like :

```
jQuery("input[type=radio]").on("change", function(){
    alert("Alerted!")
    /*Write your code here*/
});
```

```js
jQuery("input[type=radio]").on("change", function(){
    alert("Alerted!")
    /*Write your code here*/
    if (this.value === "ctl00" ) {
        $("#PasswordExpireReason").hide();
    }
    else {
       $("#PasswordExpireReason").show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span title="Yes" class="ms-RadioText">
  <input name="ctl00$m$g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581$ff111$ctl00$RadioButtons" id="ctl00_m_g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581_ff111_ctl00_ctl00" type="radio" value="ctl00">
  </span>
  <span title="No" class="ms-RadioText">
  <input name="ctl00$m$g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581$ff111$ctl00$RadioButtons" id="ctl00_m_g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581_ff111_ctl00_ctl01" type="radio" value="ctl01">
  </span>

<div>
<span id="PasswordExpireReason">This is the password expiry reason</span>
</div>
```

You can also use jQuery's [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) for selecting the first descendent radio input element after the span, though this is not a right way of doing this.

Selector to fetch the radio input with title "Yes" and No :

```
$('span.ms-RadioText[title=Yes]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0);
$('span.ms-RadioText[title=No]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0);
```

To get whether radio button with title "Yes" and "No" is checked or not :

```
$('span.ms-RadioText[title=Yes]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0).is(":checked")
$('span.ms-RadioText[title=No]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0);.is(":checked")
```

```js
// Password Expire (Yes) 
$('span.ms-RadioText[title=Yes]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0).click(function() { 
if ($('span.ms-RadioText[title=Yes]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0).is(":checked")) { $("#PasswordExpireReason").hide(); } }); 
// Password Expire (No) 

$('span.ms-RadioText[title=No]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0).click(function() { if ($('span.ms-RadioText[title=No]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0).is(":checked")) { $("#PasswordExpireReason").show(); } });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span title="Yes" class="ms-RadioText">
  <input name="ctl00$m$g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581$ff111$ctl00$RadioButtons" id="ctl00_m_g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581_ff111_ctl00_ctl00" type="radio" value="ctl00">
  </span>
  <span title="No" class="ms-RadioText">
  <input name="ctl00$m$g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581$ff111$ctl00$RadioButtons" id="ctl00_m_g_b9122b13_e38a_4fc7_b14d_4cb582079581_ff111_ctl00_ctl01" type="radio" value="ctl01">
  </span>

<div>
<span id="PasswordExpireReason">This is the password expiry reason</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The click event isn't working this way.  No error.

$('span.ms-RadioText[title=Yes]').closest("input").click(function() {

Comment: Yes, it won't work with .closest() because closest finds the elements when traveling up the DOM tree. I have updated my answer and it will work now with the use of `.find()` of jQuery.

Comment: Did you try using the `.find()`?

Comment: Here's the lastest in what I've tried. Is this right?

`// Password Expire (Yes)
`$('span.ms-RadioText[title=Yes]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0).click(function() `{
    if ($('span.ms-RadioText[title=Yes]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0).is(":checked")) {
     $("#PasswordExpireReason").hide();
    }
   });
      
   // Password Expire (No)  
   $('span.ms-RadioText[title=No]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0).click(function() {
    if ($('span.ms-RadioText[title=No]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0).is(":checked")) {
     $("#PasswordExpireReason").show();
    }
   });

Comment: Kind of tricky to show my code in the comments.  Here's an image of the code that I have now.  https://i.imgur.com/si1LZ7u.png

Comment: Yes, looks correct. Is it working ? I tried doing this in a JSFiddle which seems to be working. https://jsfiddle.net/d071zv2L/

Comment: And, There is a better way of doing this : https://jsfiddle.net/ny5guvh6/ . I have updated my answer also.

Comment: Thanks rprakash.  I see that it's working on your jsfiddle.  Although I haven't got it working yet on my SharePoint form, I know it should work so I'll mark this one as answered.

Comment: I figured out why my version of the code wasn't working.  To make the code simpler to post I didn't include the div and table that the source above is nested in.  I decided to put the full path in front of the code the solution you gave above and it now works for me. 

$('#PasswordExpire table tbody tr td span.ms-RadioText[title=Yes]').find("input[type=radio]").eq(0).click(function() {